# Transfering contacts from Lumia 520 to SIM

Tags: contacts

Is it even possible? I've googled quite a lot now and I can't find it anywhere, only videos, where people import contacts from SIM to the phone.

Is there even a chance to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, Windows Phone / Mobile does not provide a way to move your contacts to the SIM card.

If you want to transfer your contacts your best bet is to export them from your outlook.com account.

Comment: Thanks. That's just another reason, why I will not buy Windows phone anymore.